# anonymous function vs identical named function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues with writing some of my first JQuery code. I'm experimenting with some Codecademy stuff, just messing around and seeing how it works. Right now I'm pretty confused about an issue with anonymous functions: calling a function anonymously works but naming the function and calling it by name does not. The code is supposed to, on clicking an icon, open a menu from the left side of the screen and shift the rest of the page to the right; then do the reverse on clicking the close icon. The first code block works perfectly, the second just opens and closes the menu immediately after the page loads and then does nothing. Is there something I'm missing about order of operations in JS/JQuery or what?

Anonymous:

```
function main() {
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({left:'0px'}, 200);
    $('body').animate({left:'285px'}, 200);
  });
  $('.icon-close').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({left:'-285px'}, 200);
    $('body').animate({left:'0px'}, 200);
  });
}
```

Named:

```
function main() {
  $('.icon-menu').click(open());
  $('.icon-close').click(close());
}

function open() {
  $('.menu').animate({left:'0px'}, 200);
  $('body').animate({left:'285px'}, 200);
}
function close() {
  $('.menu').animate({left:'-285px'}, 200);
  $('body').animate({left:'0px'}, 200);
}
```

Thanks to anybody who can enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
$('.icon-menu').click(open());
```

`()` calls a function.

You are calling `open` **immediately** and then passing its return value (`undefined`) to `click`.

Remove the `()` and pass the function instead.

Comment: Now, to find the canonical dup...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parentheses. `open()` and `close()` call the functions, but you just want to pass a reference to the function.

```
function main() {
  $('.icon-menu').click(open);
  $('.icon-close').click(close);
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see! Thanks, I knew it was something dumb like that. But what if I had a function with parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets after function within clickhandler, because you are executing them emediatly with this syntax.